# Learning roadmap for Complex Geometry

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, manifolds, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I am still an undergraduate and I have taken courses like complex analysis and differential geometry. Also, I learnt myself manifold theory. (the book by Loring Tu).

Currently, I am quite interested in complex geometry, where I guess it is the intersection between complex analysis and geometry. But what is the roadmap for me to reach that research field? What particular mathematics is required? Do I need to learn PDE?

Comment: Read Griffith and Harris "Principles of Algebraic Geometry".

Comment: I mean, what is the prerequisite to reading these books? @MoisheKohan

Comment: General topology, differentiable manifolds, complex analysis. PDEs are not required for that book.

Comment: Thank you. But in the future, if I want to do about complex geometry, is PDE required?

Comment: It depends on the subfield, but, regardless, it is a very good idea to learn PDEs.

Comment: As an alternate option, I have heard good things about Huybrechts - "Complex Geometry". Also Riemann surfaces are a fun thing, I like Donaldson's book, it is very welcoming.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest starting with something like smooth manifolds by John Lee together with some good text on elementary complex analysis, such as the classical book by Ahlfors. I'd then learn a little about sheaves from, e.g., Gunning and Rossi's classic book -- Analytic functions of several complex variables. Then I'd start working through Huybrechts' Complex Geometry, Principles of Algebraic Geometry by Griffiths--Harris, and for additional details Voisin's book on Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry.